# Importing tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter and somewhat new to python.
I have seen two different ways to import `tkinter` from tutorials.
One, `import tkinter` is also used to import math, random, etc.
Another, `from tkinter import *` is similar to importing a class from a module.
They both seem to work.

Is there any difference between the two, and assuming so, what indicates when to use one or the other?